# Most efficient way to apply Look Up Tables to NUMPY array in Python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to squeeze as much performance as I can using numpy arrays.

I have a Look Up Table say for e.g. MYLUT = [0,2,5,7,8,12,-1,...,229]

And I have an numpy array MYARRAY with uint8 values of shape (300,200000)

What is the fastest way to apply the lookup table to all the elements in MYARRAY?

Currently I am just using for loop:

```
for i in range(300) :
    for j in range(200000) :
        MYARRAY[i][j] = MYLUT[MYARRAY[i][j]]
```

Can I do better? Or this is already the fastest way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MYLUT[MYARRAY]` should work:

---

```
MYLUT = np.array([0,2,5,7,8,12,-1,229])
MYARRAY = np.random.randint(0,8,8).reshape(4,2)

MYARRAY
#array([[5, 4],
#       [7, 5],
#       [4, 3],
#       [1, 5]])

new_array = np.empty_like(MYARRAY)
for i in range(4) :
    for j in range(2) :
        new_array[i,j] = MYLUT[MYARRAY[i,j]]

new_array
#array([[ 12,   8],
#       [229,  12],
#       [  8,   7],
#       [  2,  12]])

MYLUT[MYARRAY]
#array([[ 12,   8],
#       [229,  12],
#       [  8,   7],
#       [  2,  12]])
```

Comment: This seems like a little faster that using numpy.take. Oh hey since I am here, how do I create a numpy array of shape say (100,1000) and every element of the row holds the value of the index of the row so for row 0 the array elements would be [0,0,...0] (<- a 1000 of them) and the last row would be [999, 999, ... 999]. Right now I am just using list comprehension to do it and then casting it using numpy.asarray()

Comment: You can do `np.repeat(np.arange(100), 1000).reshape(100, 1000)` or `np.broadcast_to(np.arange(100)[:,None], (100, 1000))`. I assume you mean `99` when you say `999` since there are total 100 rows?

Comment: Nice! Thanks man! Oh yes you are right.. it should be [99,99,...99].

Answer (score 10):

NumPy can do this very efficiently:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,0,1]])
lut = np.array([0,2,5,7,8,12])
print(lut.take(arr))
```

It gives:

```
array([[2, 5, 7],
       [0, 0, 2]])
```

Note this does the same thing as `lut[arr]`.  Also note you should pay attention to your dtypes--in your example data you have -1 in the LUT but you say your data is unsigned.

If you want to be extra-efficient, you can use the `out` parameter of `take()`:

```
lut.take(arr, out=arr)
```

That avoids creating a new array, and is more similar to your original code which updates `arr` in place.

Comment: `lut.take( arr, mode="clip" )` can be useful; the default is `mode="raise"` .